# Issue when using embedded YouTube API for app

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I made an app that can watch videos uploaded on YouTube through YouTube API.

I saved the URL, channel name, and thumbnail of the videos in my database and it's being called up from the app and played back.

Due to YouTube's policy, I know that it is possible to provide videos that the original author did not reject through embedding, so please let me know if it is possible to save URLs, channel names, and thumbnails in my database.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your problem. Legal concernes?

Comment: Yes, I wonder if it is not a problem to save YouTube-related data in my DB regarding Google Policy or legally.

Comment: Ok. Keep in mind that your question is not strictly related to a programming problem, and Stackowerflow has general rules to follow. [Docs here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you can find answers on [other communities](https://stackexchange.com/sites)